# How do I build a C# .NET Docker Image with competing .NET frameworks?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently tasked with implementing continuous integration for a codebase in Visual Studio. There are components of the solution that use ASP.NET, .NET 6.0, and .NET framework 4.8.

Currently, I'm trying to build a Dockerfile that allows me to run my unit tests as build targets, so that I only publish the app and push the image to Docker Hub once the unit tests pass.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
# Build stage for .NET Framework 4.8 components
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build-net48
WORKDIR /src

# Copy .NET Framework projects 
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/ExcelWrapper/ExcelWrapper.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/ExcelWrapper/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BulkInserter/BulkInserter.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BulkInserter/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/GisJsonHandler/GisJsonHandler.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/GisJsonHandler/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/LargeJSONParser/LargeJSONParser.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/LargeJSONParser/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSDataImporter/PAMSDataImporter.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSDataImporter/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSImportCL/PAMSImportCL.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSImportCL/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSDataImporter/BAMSDataImporter.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSDataImporter/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSImportCL/BAMSImportCL.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSImportCL/"]

COPY ["ProjectBuilder/PBLogic/PBLogic.csproj", "ProjectBuilder/PBLogic/"]

# Build .NET Framework projects
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/ExcelWrapper/ExcelWrapper.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BulkInserter/BulkInserter.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/GisJsonHandler/GisJsonHandler.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/LargeJSONParser/LargeJSONParser.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSDataImporter/PAMSDataImporter.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/PAMSImportCL/PAMSImportCL.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSDataImporter/BAMSDataImporter.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release
RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder.Utilities/BAMSImportCL/BAMSImportCL.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release

RUN msbuild ProjectBuilder/PBLogic/PBLogic.csproj /nologo /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release

# Build stage for the .NET 6 components
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-dotnet6
WORKDIR /src

# Copy the .NET 6 projects and restore
COPY ["ProjectBuilder/ProjectBuilder.Core/ProjectBuilder.Core.csproj", "ProjectBuilder/ProjectBuilder.Core/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder/ProjectBuilder.DataAccess/ProjectBuilder.DataAccess.csproj", "ProjectBuilder/ProjectBuilder.DataAccess/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC/ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC/"]
COPY ["ProjectBuilder.Services/ProjectBuilder.Services.csproj", "ProjectBuilder.Services/"]

RUN dotnet restore "ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC/ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC.csproj"

# Copy the rest of the solution files
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build "ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC/ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Create a new build target called testrunner
FROM build-dotnet6 AS testrunner
# Testing .net 6 code
WORKDIR /src/ProjectBuilder/ProjectBuilder.Tests
CMD ["dotnet", "test", "ProjectBuilder.Tests.csproj", "--logger:trx"]
# Testing .net framework 4.8 code
WORKDIR /src/ProjectBuilder/PBLogic.Test
CMD ["dotnet", "test", "PBLogic.Test.csproj", "--logger:trx"]

# Publish solution
FROM build-dotnet6 AS publish
WORKDIR /src/ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC 
RUN dotnet publish "ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=build-dotnet6 /app/build .
COPY --from=build-net48 /src/ProjectBuilder.Utilities /app/ProjectBuilder.Utilities
COPY --from=build-net48 /src/ProjectBuilder/PBLogic /app/PBLogic  

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC.dll"]
```

I build the image with the following command:

```
docker build -f "C:pbweb\ProjectBuilder.Web.MVC\Dockerfile" --target testrunner -t projectbuilderwebmvc_unittest:latest "C:\pbweb"
```

When I run the container, it tells me:

```
error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
```

I've tried adding a second target for the unit tests that test .net framework 4.8 code, like so:

```
FROM build-net48 AS testrunner48
WORKDIR /src/ProjectBuilder/PBLogic.Test
CMD ["dotnet", "test", "PBLogic.Test.csproj", "--logger:trx"]
```

but that give me MSBuild error 1009, the project file doesn't exist. I can run the non .net 4.8 framework tests in a container with no issues, but the 4.8 tests are where there are issues.

Basically, I'm new to Docker, new to CI, and am struggling. Any other pointers on improving my Docker build process would be appreciated as well. Am I going about it correctly in terms of splitting up the copy and build stages based on framework? Are there other glaring inefficiencies that I am not noticing since I'm new to the tools?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're already copying the entire solution into build-dotnet6, so the easiest thing would be to combine the 1st two stage into one FROM `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` (which contains the .NET 4.8 SDK, the .NET 7 SDK and the .NET 6 & 7 runtimes) and then build everything in the same stage. That will also set you up to have your test stage run in a container that has .NET 4.8 and .NET 6

Additional notes:

- As of now you're not building in the `build-net48` stage, you're only restoring the projects.
- If you have a .sln file referencing the relevant projects you can copy that to the container and then call restore / build on that so that you don't need to invoke a command for each project.
- You don't need to copy and restore the projects separately from build, but it does speed up incrementally building the image as changes in the code won't invalidate the cached layer for restoring.